# How to collapse a dataView control by default?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a dataview control from the ExtLib and it is categorized. However the categories are expanded by default. How can I set this to collapsed?

I have seen code for the viewpanel control, but this does not apply to the dataview control.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the `expandLevel` property to 1 on the view data source:

```
<xp:dominoView ... expandLevel="1">
```